# Where all gods left?

Tags: gods, goddess, kali-yuga

As per my knowledge, at the start of Kaliyuga all gods left from earth and no one knows where they went. Till Kaliyuga they were staying on earth so where they all went and how/when will they come back.Also, why did they leave and if there is a better place/planet they aware of ,so why we are here. Why did they left us here?

Comment: "Till Kaliyuga they were staying on earth". Where did you read this?

Comment: I saw it in mahabharat episode(old one)

Comment: This is Kal chakra. In that Kaliyuga has to happen. The path of darkness is Kaliyuga where humanity will lose its peace, love, compassion, devotion, Dharma, ahimsa, satya, and in turn will develop, commerical mind, (if i do this, give me this in return), iccha of body, iccha of kama, desires, and be self centered. so whatever action one does for his wants, he thinks thats right. No knowledge of sat, asat, good bad. Its life of sharira, mind iccha. No different than animals. each one should understand this and try to find a way to overcome these traits and purify the mind!

Comment: The day you purify the mind, you can see all Gods!

Comment: Have you seen any gods? In turiya, can gods easily visibly manifest/appear/summoned if prayed with devotion?